# How to limit frequency of calls to model functions in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just learning [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/) and picking apart the first example, a todo list connected to a todo javascript model.

In the html we have:

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining</span>
```

In the controller script we have:

```
$scope.remaining = function () {

    // --> THIS ALERT IS CALLED ON EACH KEYSTROKE
    alert('remaining called');

    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function (todo) {
        count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
    return count;
};
```

I'm thinking this could become a latency problem if on each keystroke all the references to the controller have to be evaluated.

What approach, if any, could be used to make this more efficient?

Comment: Is there anything else in your page? If anything that bound with the current scope then it will be evaluated on each keystroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $watch method on scope to react when todos changed. 
I cant say is this way better for performance.

```
$scope.$watch('todos', function() {
    $scope.remaining = ... // remaining just int
}, true);
```

Also, if you use new angular, look to [$watchCollection](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection) method.

Comment: Agree with this way. The $watch only get fired if there is a change in the value of the `todos` if not, the code won't be executed.